# JavaScript Recorded audio has unknown duration

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-mediarecorder

okay so I successfully created a structure to record and download audio. But the problem is the final downloaded file has unknown **duration**. is there any way to work around that??
Here is my code (it's in Typescript)

```
let recorder: MediaRecorder,
dataArray: Blob[]

async function InitializeAudio(): Promise<void> {
    let audioIN = { audio: true }
    try {
        const mediastremObj = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(audioIN)
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediastremObj)
        recorder = mediaRecorder
        recorder.ondataavailable = (ev)=>{
            dataArray.push(ev.data)
        }
        recorder.onstop = (ev) => {
            const downloadTag = document.querySelector('#file-download') as HTMLAnchorElement
            const audioFile = new Blob(dataArray, {'type': 'audio/mp3;'})
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(audioFile)
            downloadTag.href = url
            downloadTag.download = `my-${Date.now()}-audio.mp3`
            downloadTag.click()
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
            dataArray = []
        }
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt the media recorder will create an mp3. I’d look to see what’s actually exported

Comment: @DanielA.White Yeah the media recorder returns an object that when `data` is available, returns an audio Blob. But I don't quite know where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay so after weeks of searching and researching, i found out that the media recorder API can only record in mime types supported by the browser. in chrome browser the only supported mime type is `audio/webm`, and the generated Blob can't be converted to any other mimetype. i was able to find a lasting solution using wavesufer & lamejs libraries.

link to them

https://www.npmjs.com/package/wavesurfer.js?activeTab=readme

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lamejs

you might have an error using the lame js library, so here is a link to a refactored fork of the lame js project

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lamejstmp